# Is it right how to pass the id ? I didn't understand the error?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, mvvm

```
/*****here the Adapter of my list *****/

class CurrencyMenuAdapter(
var viewModel : MainViewModel,
var currencyList: ObservableList<CurrencyRoomItem>) : ObservableRecyclerViewAdapter<CurrencyRoomItem, BaseViewHolder<CurrencyRoomItem>>(currencyList){
private val TAG = "CurrencyMenuAdapter"
private val model = MainViewModel()
override fun onCreateViewHolder(
    parent: ViewGroup,
    viewType: Int
): BaseViewHolder<CurrencyRoomItem> {
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder: 1")
    return Holder(
        ItemcurrencymenuBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )
    )
}
override fun onBindViewHolder(
    holder: BaseViewHolder<CurrencyRoomItem>,
    position: Int
) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder: 1")
    holder.bind(currencyList[position])


}
inner class Holder(private val binding:ItemcurrencymenuBinding) :
    BaseViewHolder<CurrencyRoomItem>(binding.root) {
    override fun bind(item: CurrencyRoomItem) {
        binding.item = item
        binding.btnCurrency.setOnClickListener{
            viewModel.goToRoom(item.id!!)
            Paper.book().write(Const.SAVE_ID, item.id)


        }
    }
}
```

}
/*********************************************************************************************/
/*********************************************************************************************/
/*********************************************************************************************/

/*****Here the ViewModel*****/

class MainViewModel:BaseViewModel() {

```
var firstName = ObservableField<String>()
var lastName = ObservableField<String>()
var userEmail = ObservableField<String>()
var phoneNumber = ObservableField<String>()
var listRoom= ObservableArrayList<CurrencyRoomItem>()
lateinit var id :String
private var useCase = GetCurrenciesMenuUseCase()
init {
}
fun goToRoom(groupId:String){
  getNavigator()!!.town(groupId)
}
```

/*****ViewModel*****/

/***** here the Activity*****/

class MainActivity : BaseActivity(), MainNavigator {

```
private lateinit var model: MainViewModel
private lateinit var alertDialog: AlertDialog
var dialog: Dialog? = null
override fun hideLogoutDialog() {
    alertDialog.dismiss()
}

var loginResponse = ObservableField<LoginResponse>()
override fun town(groupId: String) {

    startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, CurrencyRoomActivity::class.java))
    finish()
}
```

/*****Activity*****/

/****here the BaseViewModel****/

```
abstract class BaseViewModel<N> : ViewModel() {
private  var mCompositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable();
private lateinit var mNavigator: WeakReference<N>

fun getNavigator(): N? {
    return mNavigator?.get()
}

fun setNavigator(navigator: N) {
    this.mNavigator = WeakReference(navigator)
}
override fun onCleared() {
    mCompositeDisposable.dispose()
    super.onCleared()
}

fun getCompositeDisposable(): CompositeDisposable {
    return mCompositeDisposable
}
```

}

/****BaseViewModel****/

/******Erorr******/

//here the erorr
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/955oy.png)

/******Erorr******/

Comment: can you add a bit of an explanation to what your code is trying to do? also can you share the error message here in the question and not just a link

Answer (score 1):

The error means that mNavigator is used before it has a value, by saying lateinit you "promise" that that is never the case.

You call getNavigator before calling setNavigator though (you never call setNavigator)

To fix it you just have to call setNavigator before calling getNavigator. That would fix your specific problem but getNavigator and setNavigator seem a bit weird, perhaps consider initializing it in the constructor

Edit:

I guess you need to pass MainActivity as it extends MainNavigator to setNavigator. In that case just use the ViewModel variable in MainActivity and call

```
viewModel.setNavigator(this)
```

MainActivity extends MainNavigator and MainViewModel extends BaseViewModel so that should work

Comment: and what can i pass in parametr when i call it ?

Comment: Honestly can't tell, it seems like MainActivity would have to be passed as it extends MainNavigator but I don't know what tutorial you tried to follow and I would have used stuff like the new navigation component. However check the updated answer, that should work as well.

Comment: sorry :/ the same error

Comment: You need to call setNavigator before getNavigator is called, when you call setNavigator in onCreate and only only call getNavigator in the onClickListener the error shouldn't happen

Comment: u mean in baseActivity ? only there i have Oncreate function  ?

Comment: You must have one in MainActivity as well right? Otherwise add it there